# Google+ social network in depth

Tags: google-plus, social-networking

In what language is Google+ written (server side) ?

Facebook is written in Php and compiled in C++ for example.

Edit: how do they manage to link the +1 from google search, to your profile ?

Comment: Does it matter? It's much more interesting how they store data or how they send or gather notifications, etc..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The server identifies itself als "GSE": "Google Servlet Engine". An open source ["minigse" is available](https://code.google.com/p/opengse/source/browse/#svn/trunk/engines/minigse/java/com/google/opengse)

So it's likely a java frontend server stack.

But who cares about that anyway? The client is what matters, and google has 2 powerfull tools for web apps: closure and gwt. Given a DOM variable "closure_uid_[...]" I'd say closure is in use. Somewhere.

What else can we see?
- Images are served from "googleusercontent" and a webserver that calls itself fife
- - Heavy caching. It takes some time until a user image is updated
- GoogleTalk is integrated "as-is". Barely anything too special. Integration is very gmail like.
- Flash is still used (chat audio notifications)
- Content is duplicated to the new stream on "reshare"
- - This means that every user has a personal stream where content is copied
(Found this while google retired the "Mark Zuckerberg" fake account: reshared content was live, with wrong name {The user was renamed to "Fake Zuckerberg", but the postings stayed as "Mark Zuckerberg"})

The +1 click is routet through the top bar: gbar.pw.clk(this);

Now the topbar could just talk with the plusone core: both know your login and both services trust each other. There is really nothing special to do for this.

**UPDATE**

Here is a snippet from the Android app:

```
I/RealTimeChat(30274): Processing stream features
```

So they've most likely build it on top of their XMPP infrastructure (like gtalk and wave). Furthermore one dev talked about the circles editor and about JS coding. Thus clojure should be regarded as confirmed.